# tmux and Vim: Escape key being seen as ^[ and having long delay

Tags: vim, macvim, tmux

In MacVim and terminal Vim, everything works fine and I have no problems. As soon as I jump into tmux and run Vim there, the escape key starts having a delay of about 1 second and shows up in Vim as `^[`.

I'll hit the escape key to exit insert mode but around a 1 second delay will happen before Vim reacts and takes me back to normal mode.

If I type `Ctrl+o` to get temporarily to insert mode it immediately pops into normal mode with no delay.

If I type `jj` to get to normal mode (a shortcut I set) it still takes around a second. This leads me to think that the problem may be with Vim and not tmux

I've already set `set -sg escape-time 0` in my tmux.conf but it hasn't helped at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same Vim binary in both cases? On my Snow Leopard system, it appears that Apple's bundled Vim doesn't have the delay, but the one that comes with MacVim does.

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed that I'm always running MacVim.

Comment: Also note that it isn't Vim in general being slow, just the Escape command. Everything else runs fast. But since Escape is used very often, it makes using Vim in tmux very frustrating.

Comment: Ack, my mistake. My Vims (both Apple-supplied and MacVim) also behave exactly as you described (no pause outside of tmux/screen, but pause inside of tmux/screen). How mysterious.

Answer (score 39):

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/esc-key-causes-a-small-delay-in-terminal-due-to-its-alt-behavior.

The issue is with a tmux escape delay. The tmux setting below should correct it:

`set -s escape-time 0`

Comment: While this solved my problem, it clearly does not solve the original poster's problem: he mentions that he already has this setting, and also that using an alternate vim mapping does not help.

Comment: I was experiencing this same issue with Neovim, and thought it was a bug in nvim, but sure enough it was a Tmux setting. This fixed my issue.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue with spacemacs, and this solved it.

Comment: I'll add to this answer that I had to completely kill tmux in all terminal windows before this fix took effect. Thanks for the help cheers mate.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that escape is the first character of all function keys, arrows, mouse clicks (they are sent to vim by a terminal using some escape sequence), … Hence vim waits for next character at most 'ttimeoutlen' ('timeoutlen' if 'ttimeoutlen' is -1) milliseconds in order to be sure you meant pressing escape and not, for example, `<F1>`. There is no way to get rid of this delay, but you can narrow it down:

```
set timeout timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=100
```

. This way it will wait 1 second for you to finish the mapping, but only 0.1 second for terminal to finish sending the escape sequence.

Comment: How does screen handle this? I haven't noticed any significant delay for vim within screen.

Comment: Since the OP mentions that Vim works fine in the terminal (without tmux), this isn't the isuse.